# Como adicionar options a um drop-down list usando jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery, dropdown

Tenho uma função no `jQuery` que recebe um `array` vindo do `PHP`, através do  `$.post`. O `array` vem assim:

```
array(
    '0' => array(
        'ID' => '1',
        'NOME' => 'João'
    ),
    '1' => array(
        'ID' => '2',
        'NOME' => 'Maria'
    ),
    '2' => array(
        'ID' => '3',
        'NOME' => 'Marcos'
    ),
)
```

Como faço para através do jQuery, adicionar `option` em um `select` com os dados desse array? 
Exemplo:

```
<select>
 <option value="ID">"NOME"</option>
</select>
```

Este é o `$.post` que estou a receber o `array` vindo do php

```
$.post('/consulta/usuario', {id:id}, function(dados){
        alert(dados);
}, 'json');
```

Eu pego o `id` de acordo com a opção que o usuário escolhe, e do lado do php estou retornando o `array`:

```
echo json_encode($usuario);
```

Comment: O que dá `alert(typeof dados);`? dá string?

Comment: @Sergio não da nada, não aparece a caixa de alert

Comment: Vês algo de errado nas ferramentas do browser? vês o pedido feito e o retorno? (developer tools > network)

Comment: @Sergio depois de muito fuçar, percebi que ele está dando erro pois alguns dos campos do array estão vindo com acento do BD

Comment: E corrigindo isso já funciona? que tipo de erro deu?

Comment: @Sergio funcionou, tava dando erro por conta do utf8, agora consegui fazer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tem duas formas, usando um laço each ou for.

Vou demonstrar usando o for

```
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var id    =   data[i]['ID'];
    var name  =   data[i]['NOME'];
    var $option  =  $( '<option />' ).val(id).text(name);
    $( 'select' ).append( $option );
}
```

Vou deixar a forma do each() por sua conta, é uma implementação mais agradável, você pode pesquisar isso no link: [Jquery $each()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)

Espero que te ajude

Comment: a variavel data é a variavel que recebe o response do método ajax que retorna o json do array.

Comment: Estou tentando aqui porem sem sucesso, ele apenas adiciona vários options vazios...

Comment: Eu estou usando o $.post() do jquery, quando retorno o array com print_r por exemplo ele aparece os dados, quando tento utilizar o json ele aparece em branco..

Comment: Conseguiu resolver amigo ?

Comment: Consegui sim! mas utilizando o for que me explicou, não consegui usar o each()

Answer (score 1):

Presumo que recebas um JSON do PHP, ou seja que tenhas no PHP:

```
echo json_encode($array);
```

Assim no JavaScript podes iterar esse objeto assim:

```
var select = document.querySelector('select');
pessoas.forEach(function(obj) {
    var opt = document.createElement('option');
    opt.value = obj.ID;
    opt.innerHTML = obj.NOME;
    select.appendChild(opt);
});
```

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/g26bjL3r/

Comment: Acho que não entendo muito bem JavaScript puro, em qual parte você está recebendo o $array nele?

Comment: @FleuquerLima pois isso depende um pouco de como estás a passar os dados do PHP para o JavaScript. A array do PHP seria `pessoas`. Como estás a receber isso no JavaScript?

Comment: Eu estou usando o $.post() do jquery, quando retorno o array com print_r por exemplo ele aparece os dados, quando tentei colocar o json como disseram ele volta em branco.

Comment: @FleuquerLima podes colocar esse código do `$.post` na pergunta? O que dá por exemplo `alert(typeof dados);` dentro desse `$.post`?

Comment: Sim estou vendo o retorno com uso do alert, vou editar na pergunta